# How to use multiple react versions in pnpm monorepo structure

Tags: reactjs, pnpm

I have yarn + lerna based monorepo and I'm trying to migrate it to PNPM.

I couldn't find the way to use different react versions per packages in pnpm

My project structure is like this:

```
root 
ㄴ packages
   ㄴ app1  <- it requires react 18.x
   ㄴ app2  <- it requires react 18.x
   ㄴ app3  <- it requires react 17.x
   ㄴ shared
```

since the app3 is used in different environments we cannot upgrade react version like other projects.

specifying different react versions for each package.json doesn't solve the problem perfectly : it emits type error for the shared package components imported in app3. (I think that's because shared follows the root react version and the app3 follows older version.)

`overrides` config can only be used in root package.json, so I don't think it can provide way to set different versions per applications.

are there any solutions for this problem ?